# Iterate through json object in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I' Want to create a loop to check a condition on my Json object. I'm looking for a way to iterate through my json object:

Json:

```
{"tasks":[
        {
            "id":-1,
            "name":"Gantt editor",
            "code":"",
            "level":0,
            "status":"STATUS_ACTIVE",
            "start":1372608000000,
            "duration":21,
            "end":1375113599999,
            "startIsMilestone":true,
            "endIsMilestone":false,
            "collapsed":false,
            "assigs":[]
        },
        {
            "id":"tmp_fk1372575559620",
            "name":"release",
            "code":"",
            "level":1,
            "status":"STATUS_ACTIVE",
            "start":1372608000000,
            "duration":1,
            "end":1372694399999,
            "startIsMilestone":false,
            "endIsMilestone":false,
            "collapsed":false,
            "assigs":[]
        }
        ],       // number of tasks may vary
"selectedRow":8,
"deletedTaskIds":[],
"resources":
    [
        {
        "id":"tmp_1",
        "name":"Resource 1"
        }
    ],
"roles":[
        {
            "id":"tmp_1",
            "name":"Project Manager"
        }
        ],
"canWrite":true,
"canWriteOnParent":true
}
```

I know how to map it so let's assume i mapped Task and RootObject as follow:

```
public class Task
{
    public object id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public object start { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public object end { get; set; }
    public bool startIsMilestone { get; set; }
    public bool endIsMilestone { get; set; }
    public bool collapsed { get; set; }
    public List<object> assigs { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Task> tasks { get; set; }
    public int selectedRow { get; set; }
    public List<object> deletedTaskIds { get; set; }
    public List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
    public List<Role> roles { get; set; }
    public bool canWrite { get; set; }
    public bool canWriteOnParent { get; set; }
} // And etc .....
```

I know how to check the tasks manually for example for first one

```
Rootobject project = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);
    Task task = project.tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.id == "-1");
    decimal start = Convert.ToDecimal(task.start);
    decimal end = Convert.ToDecimal(task.end);
    decimal prog = Convert.ToDecimal(task.progress);
```

and then use task to check all it's attributes

How can I check all tasks ?

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: `foreach(var task in project.tasks)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to iterate through all tasks, you can use:

```
foreach (var task in project.tasks)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

or you can use LINQ to filter them, something like this:

```
foreach (var task in project.tasks.Where(t => t.id == "-1"))
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

which is basically same with your example, with only difference that Where returns IEnumerable and not just Task like FirstOrDefault in your example.

Answer (score -2):

Use JArray and JObject in json.net

there are some very good samples here

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm

Comment: OP already managed to deserialize the json to a concrete class `RootObject`. No need to deal with Json.Net anymore...